# Regex format returns empty result - C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have below text line and I intend to extract the "date" after the ",", i,e, 
**1 Sep 2015**

**Allocation/bundle report                               10835.0000 Days  report step 228,  1 Sep 2015**

I wrote the below regex code and it returns empty in the match.

```
`Regex regexdate = new Regex(@"\Allocation/bundle\s+\report\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\,\+(\S)+\s+(\S)+\s+(\S)");  // to get dates

MatchCollection matchesdate = regexdate.Matches(text);
```

Can you advice about what's wrong with the Regex format that I mentioned?

Comment: The `\A` is an anchor asserting the start of string. You must have meant `A`. `(\S)+` must be turned into `(\S+)`. Also, `\r` is a carriage return matching pattern, again remove the backslash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\A` is an anchor asserting the start of string. You must have meant `A`. `(\S)+` must be turned into `(\S+)`. Also, `\r` is a carriage return matching pattern, again remove the backslash to turn `\r` into `r`.

Use

```
@"Allocation/bundle\s+report\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\,\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Allocation%2fbundle%5cs%2breport%5cs%2b%5cS%2b%5cs%2b%5cS%2b%5cs%2b%5cS%2b%5cs%2b%5cS%2b%5cs%2b%5cS%2b%5c%2c%5cs%2b%28%5cS%2b%29%5cs%2b%28%5cS%2b%29%5cs%2b%28%5cS%2b%29&i=Allocation%2fbundle+report+10835.0000+Days+report+step+228%2c+1+Sep+2015)

[image]

Note that the last part of the regex may be made a bit more specific to match 1+ digits, then some letters and then 4 digits: `(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)` -> `(\d+)\s+(\p{L}+)\s+(\d{4})`

Comment: Thanks! This is great. Works!!

Answer (score 5):

Can you do it without Regex? Here's an example using a bit of help from LINQ.

```
var text = "Allocation/bundle report 10835.0000 Days report step 228, 1 Sep 2015";

var sDate = text.Split(',').Last().Trim();

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sDate))
{
    Console.WriteLine("No date found.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(sDate); // Returns "1 Sep 2015"
}
```

Comment: I like this approach too. I should have mentioned that my text has multiple lines. Hence, this might not work! But I would definitely use it in other cases!

Comment: @user7157732 Just apply this logic per line.

Comment: oh coool! thnx @Noppadet

Comment: I wonder which method is faster in the case of big text file. @noppadet

Comment: @user7157732 I'm not sure. I'd guess string operations would be faster than Regex in this case, but a test would be the best way to proceed. The advantage here isn't necessarily performance so much as clarity and ease of maintenance.